# how can i modify my query to not create duplicates after i have introduce the order_activities table?

Tags: mysql

Usually when joining between two tables where there is a one-to-many relationship there will be duplicates created
Which i am joining with order-activities table

```
query = f"""
    SELECT {time_period_column_name}, 
            store_id,
            st.name                                         as store_name,
            shopper_id,
            first_names,
            last_name,
            total_orders,
            total_items_picked,

             shopper_request_time,                        
             shopper_accepted_time,                          
             shopping_completed_time,
            ROUND(total_shopping_minutes, 2)                as total_shopping_minutes,
            ROUND(min_shopping_minutes, 2)                  AS min_shopping_minutes,
            ROUND(max_shopping_minutes, 2)                  AS max_shopping_minutes,
            ROUND(average_shopping_minutes, 2)              as average_shopping_minutes,
            ROUND(total_shopping_minutes / total_orders, 2) as minutes_per_order,
            ROUND(total_items_picked / total_shopping_minutes, 2) as shopping_efficiency,
            ROUND(average_order_zar, 2)                     as average_order_zar
     FROM (
              SELECT o.shopper_id,
                     o.store_id,
                     {time_period_column_name},
                     Count(1)                   AS total_orders,
                      TIMEDIFF(Max(o.shopper_request_stop), Max(o.shopper_request_start))    AS shopper_request_time,
                      TIMEDIFF(Max(o.shopper_accepted_stop), Max(o.shopper_accepted_start))     AS shopper_accepted_time,
                      TIMEDIFF(Max(o.shopping_completed_stop), Max(o.shopping_completed_start)) AS shopping_completed_time,
                     Sum(order_items_picked)    AS total_items_picked,
                     AVG(o.total) / 100.0       AS average_order_zar,
                     Min(shopping_minutes)      AS min_shopping_minutes,
                     Max(shopping_minutes)      AS max_shopping_minutes,
                     Avg(shopping_minutes)      AS average_shopping_minutes,
                     Sum(shopping_minutes)      AS total_shopping_minutes
              FROM (
                    SELECT oo.shopper_id,
                              oo.store_id,
                              oo.total,
                              order_item_counts.order_items_picked,
                              date_format(oo.created_at, '{time_period_format_str}')               AS {time_period_column_name},
                              IF(oa.status_code = 'shopper-request', oa.created_at, NULL)         AS shopper_request_start,
                              IF(oa.prev_status_code = 'shopper-request', oa.created_at, NULL)    AS shopper_request_stop,
                              IF(oa.status_code = 'shopper-accepted', oa.created_at, NULL)        AS shopper_accepted_start,
                              IF(oa.prev_status_code = 'shopper-accepted', oa.created_at, NULL)   AS shopper_accepted_stop,
                              IF(oa.status_code = 'shopping-completed', oa.created_at, NULL)      AS shopping_completed_start,
                              IF(oa.prev_status_code = 'shopping-completed', oa.created_at, NULL) AS shopping_completed_stop,
                              (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND, oo.started_shopping_at,
                                             oo.finished_shopping_at) / 6E7) AS shopping_minutes
                       FROM {self.market_db}.orders as oo

                           LEFT JOIN (
                               SELECT order_id, Sum(picked) as order_items_picked FROM {self.market_db}.order_items oi
                               WHERE oi.store_id IN ({store_ids_str})
                               GROUP BY oi.order_id
                           ) order_item_counts ON oo.id = order_item_counts.order_id  
                            LEFT JOIN {self.market_db}.order_activities as oa ON oo.id = oa.order_id
                            WHERE (oa.prev_status_code IN ('shopper-request',
                                                    'shopper-accepted',
                                                    'shopping',
                                                    'shopping-completed',
                                                    'collected',
                                                    'delivery')
                           OR oa.status_code IN ('shopper-request',
                                               'shopper-accepted',
                                               'shopping',
                                               'shopping-completed',
                                               'collected',
                                               'delivery'))
                        AND oa.created_at >= '{start_date}'
                        AND oa.created_at < '{end_date}'
                        AND oo.started_shopping_at IS NOT NULL
                        AND oo.finished_shopping_at IS NOT NULL
                       AND oa.status_code <> oa.prev_status_code
                       AND oo.store_id IN ({store_ids_str})
                     
                   ) AS o
              GROUP BY  shopper_id, {time_period_column_name}, store_id
              HAVING total_orders >= 1
          ) AS oc
              INNER JOIN {self.users_db}.users us
                         ON us.id = oc.shopper_id
              INNER JOIN {self.market_db}.stores st
                         ON st.id = oc.store_id                                   
     ORDER BY store_id DESC, {time_period_column_name} DESC, total_orders DESC;
        """
rows = self.run_market_query(query=query)
return rows
```

Comment: Use `SELECT DISTINCT` to get rid of duplicates.

Comment: Where should i use it in all my select statements

Comment: Just replace the first `SELECT` with `SELECT DISTINCT`.